Is definition of variable length array (VLA) / known constant size recursive?
Issue: definition of variable length array (VLA) / known constant size seems to be recursive.
C11, 6.2.5 Types, 23 (emphases added):

A type has known constant size if the type is not incomplete and is not a variable length array type.

C11, 6.7.6.2 Array declarators, 4 (emphases added):

If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

These quotes can be pseudo-coded as:
is_KCS(T) = !is_INCOMPL(T) && !is_VLA(T)
is_VLA(T) = !(is_ICE(S(T)) && is_KCS(ET(T)))

Here we see that:

is_VLA depends on is_KCS, which depends on is_VLA (and so on)
is_KCS depends on is_VLA, which depends on is_KCS (and so on)

Questions:

Is definition of variable length array (VLA) / known constant size indeed recursive?
If yes, then is it a defect in the standard?


In C2X (n3299.pdf) the quotes above a bit changed, but the issue remains.

As for me then I have understood nothing about any recursion. I do not see any recursion. The definitions are clear.

If A is not B and B is not A then it does not mean that there is a recursion. They are two different entities.

Yes, it's recursive, since for example if you have T arr[N], then whether arr is variable-length depends not only on whether N is constant, but also whether T is variable-length.  But why do you think that's a problem?  The recursion must terminate, because at some point, you get down to an array whose elements are not arrays.  C doesn't have arrays of arrays of arrays of arrays ... nesting infinitely.  It's a recursion, but it's not an infinite recursion, so it's well-defined and not circular.

@NateEldredge can you provide an example of T arr[N] where T is variable length?

int arr[x][5] where x is not a constant.  Then arr is an array of constant size 5 whose elements are of the variable-length type int[x].

6.7.6.2 refers to the element type having a known constant size, not the type itself.  So the recursive definition will terminate.  So, no, it is not a defect in the standard.

One thing missing from your pseudocode is that in order for a type to be a variable-length array type, it must in particular be an array type.  So is_VLA(T) = is_array(T) && !(is_ICE(S(T)) && is_KCS(ET(T))).  When is_VLA is "called" recursively, it's not with the same original type T, but with its element type ET(T) which is necessarily different.  The recursion could continue for a finite number of steps, but eventually either is_array() will return false or is_ICE will return true, and then the recursion terminates.

So, it makes sense for the definition to be recursive, because types in C can always be defined in terms of other types.  But this dependency relation is well founded; a C program can only define a finite number of types (because a C program is of finite length), and a type cannot be defined in terms of itself, neither directly nor indirectly, so there are no cycles.  As such, recursive definitions like this are well-defined.

@NateEldredge: I do not recall anything in the C standard that says a C program must have a finite length (although the standard allows implementations to have limits on what they will handle). Multiple things in the standard imply the length is at most aleph-null (the infinity of integers, not of real numbers or other infinities), and I suppose we would have to allow implementations to take aleph-null time to process an infinitely long program.

@EricPostpischil: Well, at least we can agree that at the point of the declaration, only a finite number of types have been previously declared or defined, and those declared later in the program are not relevant because they can't be used. I guess for Transfinite C, it should be a requirement that the characters of the program are well ordered, or something like that.

It seems to me your questions are predicated on missing or ignoring the word "element" in your second quote. is_KCS(ET(T)) is not the same as is_KCS(T).


I indeed confused the "type (itself)" with the "element type" and forgot about is_array(T) condition. Yes, "the recursion must terminate, because at some point, you get down to an array whose elements are not arrays". 2) Thanks for mentioning terms "well-founded" and "aleph-null".


@NateEldredge Extra question: is there (or are you aware of) any programming / scripting language where type can be defined in terms of itself?

Sure, it's recursive. No, it's not a problem, because the recursion terminates.
First of all, there's an implicit check you're missing (since S(T) is only defined for arrays):
is_KCS(T) = !is_INCOMPL(T) && !is_VLA(T);
is_VLA(T) = !( isARRAY(T) && is_ICE(S(T)) && is_KCS(ET(T)) );

With this change, you'll reach a type that isn't an array type, a type that's an array type without an integer constant expression for size, or an incomplete type.
Not only is it not a defect, it's necessary. Take a look at the following example:
typedef int ET[n];

ET a[4];

aka
int a[4][n];

Is a a VLA? Yes, because its element type (ET/int [n]) is a VLA type. To determine if a is a VLA, we needed to (recursively) check if ET/int [n] is a VLA type.
